# Gitlab create release after merging anything to master

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I was searching for this but couldn't find it. Is there possibility to create any custom gitlab-ci.yml that will create a release when anything is merged to master ? There is no need of big customization - some label + current date time will be enough as a tag. Currently I have deploy that works only for master branch and basically this is release :) But want to have a trace also in gitlab

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in gitlab docs in this [link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/release_cicd_examples.html#create-a-release-when-a-commit-is-merged-to-the-default-branch) if you don't want something too complex you can use this example or maybe edit it somehow to fit your requirements

as the docs say

> In this CI/CD example, the release is triggered when you merge a commit to the default branch. You can use this method if your release workflow does not create a tag manually

just be careful about the tag name how you wanna create and name it so it fit to your workflow